# change the class of a specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put together a page which contains several tables with data. Since the page can become long I want the user to be able to collapse the tables by clicking the header. I plan to use a + icon to indicate that there is more content available and - icon to show that it is collapsible. So I need to switch the class name of the i tag which is the icon. Like I said the page can contain several tables with identical i tags tags so I need something to cover that

Here is example HTML.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="heading" id="thead">
      <tr id="tr">
         <th id="th" colspan="3"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Basic info</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="content">
        <tr>
          <td>Registration</td>
          <td>ABC 123</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="heading" id="thead">
      <tr id="tr">
         <th id="th" colspan="3"><i class="icon-plus"></i> More info</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="content">
        <tr>
          <td>Start time</td>
          <td>11:57</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.content').show();
  jQuery('.heading').click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next('.content').slideToggle('0');
    jQuery(this).parent().next("i").removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');
  });
});
</script>
```

the showing and hiding of the tbody works fine but I cant get the icon to change, any clues?

Comment: invalid markup : multiple similar `id` value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
jQuery(this).parent().next("i").removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');
```

to

```
jQuery(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
```

Comment: seems to do what I want, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

ok first of all never give multiple elements the same ID in a page... ever. Very bad practice and will cause complications when needing to refer to one specific element.

As for the jquery, use addClass and removeClass:

```
jquery('.headingClass').removeClass('.headingclass');
jquery(this + 'i').addClass('.headingclass');
```

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.content').show();
  jQuery('.heading').click(function()
  {
    jquery('.headingClass').removeClass('.headingclass');
    jquery(this + 'i').addClass('.headingclass');
    jQuery(this).next('.content').slideToggle('0');
    jQuery(this).parent().next("i").removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sweet, I'm aware of never using the same ID, its just a copy'n'paste error in the example but thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `jQuery(this).parent().next("i")`, use `jQuery(this).find("i")`

In your sample, `jQuery(this)` is the thead element; the `i` element you want to reference is a descendant, not a sibling, so `.parent().next("i")` tries to match an element at the same level as your thead and tbody elements!

Answer (score 0):

try this ( without icon of + and - )

**note :** i have changed the markup a bit.

#### CSS

```
i { padding:4px; cursor:pointer; }
.icon-minus {  color :red; }
.icon-minus:before { content:"-";}
.icon-plus { color :green }
.icon-plus:before { content:"+";}
```

#### HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead class="heading" >
    <tr >
        <th colspan="3" ><i class="icon-minus"></i>Basic info</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="content">
<tr>
    <td>Registration</td>
    <td>ABC 123</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead class="heading" >
    <tr >
        <th colspan="3"> <i class="icon-minus"></i>More info</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="content">
<tr>
    <td>Start time</td>
    <td>11:57</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**​jQuery**

```
jQuery('.heading').bind('click',function(){
       jQuery(this).siblings('tbody').slideToggle('0');
       jQuery(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-minus icon-plus');
});
```

​

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rELfz/)**